# Realizar soma de campo na tabela

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Possuo uma View que me retorna dados que o contribuinte pagou a previdência no ano atual, onde retorno o pagamento mensal do mesmo.
Necessito realizar a soma dos meses, criando um subTotal mensal.

Atualmente eu possuo esses dados em minha View: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Necessito que em cada mês faça a soma com o mês anterior, ficando assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esses dados eu retorno por uma action em meu controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var usuario =
                previdenciaRepository.Previdencias.Where(p => p.CdMatricula == matricula && p.SqContrato == contrato).ToList();       

            return View(usuario);
        }
```

E retorno os dados em minha View:

```
@model IEnumerable<PortalRH.DomainModel.Entities.Previdencia>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}    
<h2>Index</h2>

<table class="table">
    <tr>

        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NmPessoa)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contribuinte)
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NmPessoa)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Contribuinte)
            </td>  
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Classe Previdência:

```
 public class Previdencia
    {
        [Key]
        public Int64 Cod_Previdencia { get; set; }
        public int CdMatricula { get; set; }
        public Int16 SqContrato { get; set; }
        public string NmPessoa { get; set; }
        public double Contribuinte { get; set; }
    }
```

Tentei realizar o cálculo por meio de um `For()`na View, ficando assim:

```
@model IEnumerable<PortalRH.DomainModel.Entities.Previdencia>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<table class="table">
    <tr>

        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NmPessoa)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contribuinte)
        </th>
        <th>
            Ano contribuinte
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NmPessoa)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Contribuinte)
            </td>  
            <td>
                @{
                    var subTotal = 0.0;
                    int contador = item.Contribuinte.ToString("c").Count();
                    for (int i = 0; i < contador; i++)
                    {
                        subTotal += item.Contribuinte;
                    }


                }
              @subTotal
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Ele percorre o `For()` corretamente. Porém neste caso o valor do `@subTotal` sempre será a soma de todos os dados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No seu lugar, eu agruparia os registros por `NmPessoa` ou algum campo identificador da pessoa:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.GroupBy(g => g.NmPessoa))
{
    var subtotal = 0;

    foreach (var contribuicoes in item.ToList()) 
    {
        subtotal += contribuicoes.Contribuinte;

        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Key)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => contribuicoes.Contribuinte)
            </td> 
            <td>
                @subtotal
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

Não sei se entendi bem. Se precisar, comente que modifico a resposta.

Não testei esse código.

Comment: É exatamente isso que preciso. Obrigado!

Comment: Agora, fazendo estes cálculos na View eu terei problemas de performasse?

Comment: @RenilsonAndrade Acho que não. O maior problema de performance, se ocorrer, ficaria no Controller.

Comment: Vlw @CiganoMorrisonMendez, obrigado mais uma vez pela ajuda.